# Can I use Windows GUI and generate the equivalent command in CLI form?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to learn CLI just by doing the things I usually do using GUI.  Is there a way to see the equivalent commands?

For example in Excel, you can record a macro and see the VBA equivalent code of what you are doing, even as you are doing it.

How about in Windows, or in any OS for that matter?

Comment: Besides not being possible, in that there aren't CLI commands for specific mouse movements.. Besides that, That is obviously not how to learn CLI. CLI came before GUI. Your analogy is ridiculous, since Macros generate code.  Mouse movements may generate code too but no CLI commands.

Answer (score 2):

In the any other OS category, you'll be happy if you ever try IBM [AIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX). AIX has a tool called [SMIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX_SMIT) which can operate in graphical mode, but which provides the command line equivalent for every operation it performs. It's a shame there aren't similar tools for non-niche operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea but it isn't out there yet it seems. That would be useful but it's kind of like having a Spanish interpreter: too much help can make trial-and-error seem like a really attractive option.